# Fix with office365 AUTH

Tags: smtp, nodemailer

I am having issues connecting my node app to Microsoft office 365 mail server I get this as errors: "SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant"

https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006Vm3uWCAR/help-with-office365-auth

please any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask Microsoft to enable this, or change your authentication method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i reach out to microsoft 365 technical support staff to activate my mail's smtp